# In react-navigation, is there an equivalent to this.props.navigation.dispatch() without using the this.props.navigation prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I see that the next react-navigation version to be released will have the `useNavigation()` hook, but is there a way in react-navigation@4.x to effectively use `this.props.navigation.dispatch()` without having to use `this.props`?

Comment: You mean [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch)?

Comment: I don't think I can use `useDispatch` from react-redux -- for react-navigation, they explicitly tell us to not use redux's dispatch, but to instead use `this.props.navigation.dispatch()` because of other logic that must run for the navigation operations to work. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a solution myself based on modifying [a recommended approach from the official react-navigation 4.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html#docsNav). The approach involves making a navigation "app container" component out of the app's stack navigator and creating a reference to that container. This reference is then used by a mediating navigation services object (here I call it `NavigationService`) that can be imported and used anywhere in my codebase.

```js
// App.js

import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';
import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";

const TopLevelNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  ...
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    defaultNavigationOptions: { gesturesEnabled: isBackGestureEnabled }
  }
  ...
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(TopLevelNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The dispatching actions I want are defined as follows (here I have methods created for adding to my navigation stack and resetting the navigation stack). (This differs from the react-navigation docs' recommendation; I had to use `_navigator.currentNavProp.dispatch()` rather than `_navigator.dispatch()`, which didn't exist for me.)

```js
// NavigationService.js

import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation";

var _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.currentNavProp.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params
    })
  );
}

function navigationReset(routeName) {
  const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName })]
  });
  _navigator.currentNavProp.dispatch(resetAction);
}

export default { navigate, navigationReset, setTopLevelNavigator };
```

And now I can use this in any of my other JavaScript files, whether they are React components or not.

```js
// anyOtherFile.js

import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

...
NavigationService.navigationReset("Home");
// or
NavigationService.navigate("Home");
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [react-navigation-hooks](https://github.com/react-navigation/hooks) library with React Navigation 4.

```js
import { useNavigation } from 'react-navigation-hooks';

function MyComponent() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // ...
}
```

You can also use the `withNavigation` HOC from the main package: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html